# How to enable PHP mail() function in a IIS7 / Win2008 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis-7, email

I have a web server where I currently host an ASP.Net Web Application that uses the IIS6 SMTP Server to send notification emails.

I installed PHP and Wordpress using the Web Plataform Installer and installed it as a subdirectory for my website. The blog is working perfectly, but it doesn't send any notification email, and says that the mail() function is not set, even though I correctly application uses.

Is there any other place I need to go to enable the mail function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need to set up these in your `php.ini`:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = mail.example.com
sendmail_from = admin@example.com
```

These work on Win32 and Win64, and let you change `mail()`'s behavior to run through SMTP.  Obviously, you have to have an SMTP server that will let you talk to it.

Mainly this is done because actually [integrating a `sendmail` equivalent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php) on Win32 is a nightmare.

Comment: above is applicable  for win64.